# JLabel refresh icon with updated image

Tags: java, swing, refresh, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to make an experiment in image manipulation.
Basically I have an image that is continously updated by a timer and i display that image in a JLabel.

My problem is that JLabel does'nt refresh the image.

Here is my timer code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            count++;

            System.out.println("timer");
            System.out.println(filename);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);

            label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(icon);
            label.setText(""+count);

            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(label);

            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            frame.repaint();
            frame.validate();

            try{
                FileWriter fstream;

                fstream = new FileWriter(filename,true);

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

                out.write("text to append");
                out.close();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Where filename is path to my image.

Image is displayed but JLabel never refresh my image.
I tested my code and is working if I swich between two different images...

EDIT:

I solved by duplicate every time last image created and renaming with a timestamp.

Comment: are you changing the filename variable or are you always using the same? From what I can tell by looking at the code you provided, filename is always the same so it will draw the same image.

Comment: Yes filename is always the same but image is updated...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
factor out anything to do with the `FileWriter`

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in that the image is not updated, im pretty sure it is. Altho I do think that the "image" is not beeing altered like you think. BufferedWriter is used to write text to a file, which you do with your call to write, but filename is a image and not a textfile. 

Try to comment out your try statement, and change filename to refeer to a different image last in your method. This will confirm if the problem lies in the updating of image and not in the refreshing

Comment: As I edited in my question I figured out creating everytime a new file with timestamp. Image is updated correctly, is an experiment about words in images so I need to write the image as if it was text. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
label.setText(""+count);

panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);

frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

frame.repaint();
frame.validate();
```

Replace all that with something like:

```
label.setIcon(icon);
```

If the label is not visible at that point, declare it as a class attribute of the outer class or at the same level as the `frame` (which is obviously accessible in that snippet).